# Tap on mobile not working

Tags: javascript, ios, console, tap

Using javascript, I am trying to get a "tap" to work on mobile and no luck. I am trying this code:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $("#someDiv").on("tap",function(){
      alert('you tapped me');
    });
}
```

And this is not doing anything. Also, as a side question, I don't have a console to look for errors on iPhone, so it's very difficult to know what is going wrong. Is there a way to check for errors on mobile?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out for how to use dev console with Safari on iOS: http://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onmousedown` event is equilevant to tap for mobile clients.

EDIT: I didn't notice it's for jquery-mobile
Documentation examples show usage of `.bind()` rather than `.on()`

Comment: There is a [tap event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) on jQuery mobile.

Comment: @NathanP. Corrected my answer.